# unresolved dependency: com.sksamuel.scapegoat#sbt-scapegoat;1.0.4: not found

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to use sbt-scapegoat by adding this to plugins.sbt:

> addSbtPlugin("com.sksamuel.scapegoat" %% "sbt-scapegoat" % "1.0.4")

My scala version is:

> 2.11.12

My sbt version is:

> 1.1.0

And I am getting this error:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.sksamuel.scapegoat#sbt-scapegoat;1.0.4: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.sksamuel.scapegoat:sbt-scapegoat:1.0.4 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.sksamuel.scapegoat:sbt-scapegoat:1.0.4 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/home/nitin/workspace/nimble/oculus-analytics/project/plugins.sbt#L43-44)
[warn]        +- default:oculus-analytics-build:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.sksamuel.scapegoat#sbt-scapegoat;1.0.4: not found
```

I have also tried specifying scapegoatVersion into build.sbt:

> scapegoatVersion := "1.3.4"

I am using IntelliJ Idea. Thnx for help in advance.

Comment: Hi, try setting scapegoat Version to 1.1.0 in your build.sbt.

Comment: Hi, @geek94 thnx for your help, but actually, scapegoat dependency(1.0.4) is not resolving and unless dependency is not resolved it doesn't matter what "scapegoatVersion" we are setting in our build.sbt. As in build.sbt we specify what version we want to use after resolving the dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
addSbtPlugin("com.sksamuel.scapegoat" % "sbt-scapegoat" % "1.0.9")
```

This plugin worked with scala version *2.11.12* and sbt version *1.1.0*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have either wrong plugin name (and need  `scalac-scapegoat-plugin`)  or use `%%` instead of `%` for `sbt-scapegoat` which does not have _<*scala version*> suffix in maven repo.

**Update**

Ah, just noted `addSbtPlugin`, so should be wrong name

Comment: Thnx for your help, but still it is not resolving and I am using `addSbtPlugin("com.sksamuel.scapegoat" %% "scalac-scapegoat-plugin" % "1.0.4")`

Comment: yep. Because plugin version available are 1.3.x and 1.4.0. See here: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22scalac-scapegoat-plugin_2.12%22

Comment: Thanx @Evgeny for your help, but it didn't work and I got the solution here is the [link](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.sksamuel.scapegoat%7Csbt-scapegoat%7C1.0.9%7Cjar)